# window closing event for jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two asp.net page. One of them is pop-up and one of them is normal page. I want to do when pop-up page will have closed my normal page's gridview will reload with ajax. How can i catch my pop-up page closed or not from my normal page? (my normal page and pop-up page have separate master page)

Answer (score 1):

You Can Bind **CLOSE** event to page using jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="js-hidden">XXX</div>
  <script>
    jQuery(window).bind(
    "beforeunload", 
    function() { 
        return confirm("Do you really want to close?") 
    }
)
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable isPopUpClosed = false and set the variable to true in pop up close event.